# Is there a better way to do these constraints in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Over half of my routes file is taken up with constraints (and their classes) and so I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach this. If I add other pets, it will be the same for each of them - so the file could get very long.

```
class AkcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[sporting-group hound-group working-group terrier-group toy-group non-sporting-group herding-group misc-class]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:akc_group]
  end
end

class AnkcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[toy-group terrier-group gundog-group hound-group working-group utility-group non-sporting-group]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:ankc_group]
  end
end

class CkcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[sporting-group hound-group working-group terrier-group toy-group non-sporting-group herding-group]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:ckc_group]
  end
end

class FciConstraint
  TYPES = %w[group-1 group-2 group-3 group-4 group-5 group-6 group-7 group-8 group-9 group-10]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:fci_group]
  end
end

class IkcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[group-1 group-2 group-3 group-4 group-5 group-6 group-7 group-8 group-9 group-10]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:ikc_group]
  end
end

class KcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[hound-group working-group gundog-group terrier-group utility-group pastoral-group toy-group]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:kc_group]
  end
end

class KusaConstraint
  TYPES = %w[hound-group working-group gundog-group terrier-group utility-group pastoral-group toy-group]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:kusa_group]
  end
end

class NzkcConstraint
  TYPES = %w[toy-group terrier-group gundog-group hound-group working-group utility-group non-sporting-group]
  def self.matches?(request)
    TYPES.include? request.path_parameters[:nzkc_group]
  end
end


# For dog groups and types
match 'dogs/akc/:akc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "akc_dogs",
                        :constraints => AkcConstraint
match 'dogs/ankc/:ankc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "ankc_dogs",
                        :constraints => AnkcConstraint
match 'dogs/ckc/:ckc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "ckc_dogs",
                        :constraints => CkcConstraint
match 'dogs/fci/:fci_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "fci_dogs",
                        :constraints => FciConstraint
match 'dogs/ikc/:ikc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "ikc_dogs",
                        :constraints => IkcConstraint
match 'dogs/kc/:kc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "kc_dogs",
                        :constraints => KcConstraint
match 'dogs/kusa/:kusa_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "kusa_dogs",
                        :constraints => KusaConstraint
match 'dogs/nzkc/:nzkc_group', :to => "dogs#index", :as => "nzkc_dogs",
                        :constraints => NzkcConstraint
```

I guess I'm concerned about performance more than anything else - should I be worried? Is there a better way?

Comment: It seems to be that you're trying to implement slugs via routes. Perhaps look at [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), et al.

Comment: Hi Andrew, they are not AR models, just fields (and values) in the Dog model. I did consider creating a 'registry' model, but that will introduce another element into the url (such as dogs/registry/akc/working-dogs etc) which I wanted to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Akc`, `Ankc`, `Ckc`, etc. all inherit from the same model, e.g. `Club` (I sure hope they do), then you can certainly make this more concise, at least, and probably more efficient. Something like this:

```
class ClubConstraint
  Types = { # in actuality this should come from your database and not be
            # hard-coded; otherwise it's going to be a big maintenance headache
    :akc  => %w[ sporting-group  hound-group    working-group
                 terrier-group   toy-group      non-sporting-group
                 herding-group   misc-class ],
    # ...
    :nzkc => %w[ toy-group       terrier-group  gundog-group
                 hound-group     working-group  utility-group
                 non-sporting-group ],
  }.freeze

  def matches? request
    pparams = request.path_parameters
    return unless club_groups = Types[ pparams[ :club ] ]

    club_groups.include? pparams[ :group ]
  end
end

# For dog groups and types
match 'dogs/:club/:group', :to => "dogs#index",
      :constraints => ClubConstraint.new
```

This may not work as written since I haven't tested it (and your `:as =>` option will need re-implementing), but you get the idea.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for the answer. They are not AR models, just fields and values from the Dog model. As I mentioned to Andrew, I did consider creating a 'registry' model, but that will introduce another element into the url (such as dogs/registry/akc/working-dogs etc) which I wanted to avoid if possible.

Comment: Pulling out the club into a url param will work nicely. That's what I would have suggested. Moving the types into a model isn't necessary as you are probably unlikely from changing these often. You'd be forced to do a deployment in order to update them instead.

Comment: Ok...finally got it! Toyed around with different ways of doing it, including a 'polymorphic' HABTM (pm on the join model - for clubs and dogs/cats) but it was just too OTT. So ended up creating two models, clubs & groups, and then used a constraint that is a mixture of Jordan's and my old one, at just 7 lines of code. My only concern is as I'm using a model to store the clubs/groups (and thus calling this model in the routes file) does this mean every time a request is sent to the site the db is hit? or does Rails cache routing queries like this? Should I be worried? Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: (PS apologies in the delay in getting back to you - I wanted to wait until I had something worth reporting!)

Comment: AFAIK in production Rails runs `routes.rb` once, when the server is started. It calls `matches?` on every relevant request, but as long as you're loading your objects before that, e.g. when the class is created, I don't think you need to worry.